# expression behind generated column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I just created a generated column 'gc1' of stored type in my table tbl1.

When I am running this command:

```
DESCRIBE tbl1;
```

It shows me the 'STORED GENERATED' for gc1 in the Extra field.

When I am checking triggers using `SHOW TRIGGERS;` command,
it is not showing me anything related to the generated column.

I am not able to get the expression used to generate the column gc1. 
I tried the MySQL documentation as well but got nothing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not with you. You must now how the generated column is constructed so what else do you need to know? And can you add the create table code please.

Comment: If I am creating it, I know it for sure. But what if someone else created the generated column and I want to see the expression for it.

Comment: IF you know the name of the table then SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>

Comment: IF you don't know the tables then information_schema.columns.GENERATION_EXPRESSION may be what you are looking for,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.7/en/columns-table.html